# wxnviz.py: No module named 'grass.lib.ogsf'

Tags: grass-gis

I'm getting the following error on starting GRASS using the GRASS 8.2.1 Docker container (source: docker pull mundialis/grass-py3-pdal:8.2.1-ubuntu):

```
    Launching <wxpython> GUI in the background, please wait...
    GRASS latlong_wgs84/PERMANENT:wxpython > 
    (wxgui.py:1277): dbind-WARNING **: 02:14:28.065: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus:       Failed to connect to socket /run/user/1000/at-spi/bus_0: No such file or directory
    wxnviz.py: No module named 'grass.lib.ogsf'
```

When the GRASS GUI appears I can see that under the 'File' menu the '3D image rendering (m.nviz.image)' is greyed out.

I get the same issue using the GRASS 7.8.7 GRASS Docker container (source: docker pull mundialis/grass-py3-pdal:7.8.7-ubuntu).

I have installed wxpython (without apparent error) within the Docker containers:

```
pip install --force-reinstall -v wxpython
```

The Docker run command I am using is this:

```
docker run -v /data/docker_tmp:/tmp:rw -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e uid=$(id -u) -e gid=$(id -g) -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY --name grass821jammy -i -t mundialis/grass-py3-pdal:8.2.1-ubuntu /bin/bash
```

I suspect the issue is related to the Docker run command, as the problem is not evident with GRASS 7.8.7 installed directly on my laptop?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried the `_wxgui` images? https://hub.docker.com/r/mundialis/grass-py3-pdal/tags?page=1&name=ubuntu

Comment: Thanks. I tried the two wxgui Docker images (8.3.0RC1 and 8.4dev) and they work fine, though there isn't a wxgui Docker image for the latest stable version as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

The correct docker image with GUI support is this one: `osgeo/grass-gis:releasebranch_8_3-ubuntu_wxgui`. We are currently moving the docker images from "mundialis" to "OSGeo" dockerhub organization. The docker images overview page will reflect that soon.

To use and run it:

```
docker run -it --rm --volume="$(pwd)/:/data" \
 --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" \
 --env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY --device="/dev/dri/card0:/dev/dri/card0" \
 osgeo/grass-gis:releasebranch_8_3-ubuntu_wxgui grass --gui
```

which will start the GUI directly (otherwise, use `bash` to enter the container and start GRASS GIS with GUI from therein).

[image]